# Proof of converse of Intermediate Value Property

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I need to prove that if a function is injective(one-one) and has Intermediate Value Property, then the function is continuous. I just need a hint as I would like to solve it on my own.
**P.S.**-Remember that Intermediate Value Property on it's own does not imply continuity.

Comment: What is the definition of 'Intermediate Value Property'?